# Spring boot with allure reports crashes with IllegalStateException on oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc, spring-aop, allure

I want to use Allure reports in my spring boot project but when I configure it and execute a test that starts the spring context I recieve this error:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access using Lookup on org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor (file:/C:/work/maven-3.5.2/maven_repo/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.8.RC2/aspectjweaver-1.9.8.RC2.jar) to class java.lang.ClassLoader
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[AppClassLoader@16f65612] abort trouble in: 
class org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder$OraclePoolDataSourceProperties extends org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder$MappedDataSourceProperties:
  public Class getDataSourceInstanceType():
                    LDC oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl   (line 641)
                    ARETURN
  end public Class getDataSourceInstanceType()
```

I have a txt file with a more detailed explanation of the error generated by Aspectj.

This is my pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>My app</name>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
        <liquibase.version>4.3.1</liquibase.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.9.8.RC2</aspectj.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc10</artifactId>
            <version>19.12.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.200</version>
            <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                    </argLine>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <property>
                            <name>junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled</name>
                            <value>true</value>
                        </property>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportVersion>2.4.1</reportVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I've been trying with different versions combinations but none of them has worked.

Comment: You might have hit [Spring issue #27650](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/27650), which I created a couple of days ago, but which has actually been a problem for quite a while in Spring (Boot). Please try my workaround there and let me know if it works. Then I can write an answer here, which then you can accept in order to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please note I only needed to add the following to my spring configuration (application.yaml):

```
spring:
    autoconfigure:
        exclude:
            - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

Hopefully something similar works for you.

However I am using Spring boot version 2.7.11 and Allure plugin version 2.11.2.